# Scale font-size on hover inside a container while keeping container dimensions, without forcing a width or height into it?

Tags: css

I have tried to make a button class that will make a hover effect of just scaling up the font-size. Sadly it came with all kinds of side effect that I did not want.

1. I want to take the hover effect from `button-2`
   *(the 'Text' and 'Short Text' button - I don't want the collapsing on multiple lines neither inside the button nor when it is hovered that happens with the 3 other buttons)* and put it inside `button-1`. So that ONLY the font-size scales up when it's hovered and nothing else.
2. But `button-1` should still work like `button-1` does when it is NOT hovered. So that it fits the text inside it regardless or the `font-size` or `font-weight` or how long the text is.

[Codeply code example](https://www.codeply.com/p/YaerHPhtku)

```css
/* The button I want - However, it don't have the effect I want so ONLY the font-size change on hover and NOTHING else */
.button-1{
    display: flex;
    border: solid 2.5px red;
    color: red;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: font-size 0.25s 0s;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    align-items: center;
}

/* The effect I want - However, it doesn't have the button i want when it is not hovered where it fits the content dynamically. */
.button-2{
    display: flex;
    border: solid 2.5px red;
    color: red;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    transition: font-size 0.25s 0s;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2rem; /* Only thing new added to button 2 */
    width: 10rem; /* Only thing new added to button 2 */
    justify-content: center; /* Only thing new added to button 2 */
}

.button-1:hover, .button-2:hover{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

ul{
    display: flex
}

nav{
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <p>The buttons I want - but NOT the hover effect I want. I ONLY want the font-size to change on hover and NOTHING else. <br>
 Right now it scales the whole button + font-size and mess with the layout of the other buttons</p>
 <ul>
  <li><a class="button-1" href="">Text</a></li> <!-- The button I want that always fit the content regardless of the text size and with 1rem in padding --> 
  <li><a class="button-1" href="">Short Text</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-1" href="">Medium Sized Button Text</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-1" href="">Large Sized Button Text Just For Show</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-1" href="">Very Long Text To Show How It Always Fit Content</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
 <p>The hover effect I want (only on the 'text' and 'short text' button the last 3 is also not the effect I want).<br>
 But now the buttons doesn't fit the content dynamically regardless of the length of the text as above when it is not hovered</p>
 <ul>
  <li><a class="button-2" href="">Text</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-2" href="">Short Text</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-2" href="">Medium Sized Button Text</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-2" href="">Large Sized Button Text Just For Show</a></li>
  <li><a class="button-2" href="">Very Long Text To Show How It Always Fit Content</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Simply put, I want button 1 *(not the hover effect from button 1)* with the font-size increase hover effect from button 2 *(the first 2 button examples)*. Preferably just as 1 class inside 1 HTML tag, but if it is not possible that way, but can be done another way to make it do what I want, that is all that really matters.

I don't know if it is possible, or there is workaround or some crazy `calc()` stuff you can do where depending on the `font-size` the text content, it sets `height` and `width` of every button.

Comment: Try using `transform: scale()` instead of `font-size`.

Comment: I must admit, I don't understand the request. How do you want to handle the text growing larger than its container? The container must grow, or the text must be truncated, or the text must escape the confines of the button (and most likely overlap the other buttons considering the size difference).

Comment: That will scale the whole button and I only want the font-size to scale up. Unless you can use transform: scale() to only target the font-size, but in that case I don't know the syntax for it, if it is possible to do that.

Comment: I am fine with the text escaping the container. If the text goes outside the border that is fine, then I can just increase/decrease padding or font-size, my main issue is the whole problem of only having font-size scale and that being the only effect. Technically it doesn't have to scale font-size if there is other ways of doing it. I just want my text to "get bigger" when I hover over it, without affecting the button, but have it work "dynamic" so I don't have to set the width and height manually.

 I might be asking for the impossible here.

Comment: Technically I have somewhat solved the problem with button-2, the issue then is that I would have to manually set height and width for every single button depending on the text inside of it and calculate what the padding has to be every time so they "look" identical, which doesn't really seem practical :( and if I later change font, text weight or something and then I would have to redo all of it etc.

Comment: Well, hopefully you can see from my answer that animating `scale` is much smoother than animating `font-size`. That just has to do with how fonts are rendered at certain fractional font-sizes. `scale` is more like taking a picture of the text and scaling that, which is much more straightforward. I'm not sure what you mean by making the buttons look identical; you can do that with flex by setting the container's `justify-content` to `space-evenly` or `space-between` and `align-content` to `stretch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered `button-1` to scale the whole button up, as you mentioned in your comment, that's not right. So I added `button-3` to show how you can achieve that affect, but you have to add another element within the anchors (in this case, a `span`). Then you just add the [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) transform function to the `span` rather than the anchor.

Note that the initial class for the button doesn't set the width and height or anything like that. You might need to adjust the padding if you want the text to not scale outside of the box.

```css
/* The button I want - However, it don't have the effect I want so ONLY the font-size change on hover and NOTHING else */

.button-1 {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 2.5px red;
  color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: transform 0.25s 0s; /* Changed from font-size to transform */
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scale(1); /* added scale(1) for non-hover state */
}


/* The effect I want - However, it doesn't have the button i want when it is not hovered where it fits the content dynamically. */

.button-2 {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 2.5px red;
  color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: font-size 0.25s 0s;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
  /* Only thing new added to button 2 */
  width: 10rem;
  /* Only thing new added to button 2 */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Only thing new added to button 2 */
}

.button-3 {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 2.5px red;
  color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  align-items: center;
}

/* added span rule to get scale and origin */
.button-3 span {
  transition: transform 0.25s 0s; 
  transform: scale(1); 
  transform-origin: center;
}

.button-1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); /* split .button-1:hover out and increased scale value for hover state */
}

.button-2:hover {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

/* Then add a :hover for the span... */
.button-3:hover span {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex
}

nav {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>The buttons I want - but NOT the hover effect I want. I ONLY want the font-size to change on hover and NOTHING else. <br> Right now it scales the whole button + font-size and mess with the layout of the other buttons</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button-1" href="">Text</a></li>
    <!-- The button I want that always fit the content regardless of the text size and with 1rem in padding -->
    <li><a class="button-1" href="">Short Text</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-1" href="">Medium Sized Button Text</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-1" href="">Large Sized Button Text Just For Show</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-1" href="">Very Long Text To Show How It Always Fit Content</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
  <p>The hover effect I want (only on the 'text' and 'short text' button the last 3 is also not the effect I want).<br> But now the buttons doesn't fit the content dynamically regardless of the length of the text as above when it is not hovered</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button-2" href="">Text</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-2" href="">Short Text</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-2" href="">Medium Sized Button Text</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-2" href="">Large Sized Button Text Just For Show</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-2" href="">Very Long Text To Show How It Always Fit Content</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav>
  <p>The hover effect I want (only on the 'text' and 'short text' button the last 3 is also not the effect I want).<br> But now the buttons doesn't fit the content dynamically regardless of the length of the text as above when it is not hovered</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="button-3" href=""><span>Text</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button-3" href=""><span>Short Text</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button-3" href=""><span>Medium Sized Button Text</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button-3" href=""><span>Large Sized Button Text Just For Show</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="button-3" href=""><span>Very Long Text To Show How It Always Fit Content</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```